# How to use end of string in square brackets in javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

In js regex, I have

```
[\.\?!][\s$]
```

what I want to do is match

literal dot, or literal question mark or explanation mark

then

either 1 whitespace character or, be at the end of the string.

However the regex above, tries to match the literal $.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: [`[.?!](?:\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/hfulTs/1) ? In your regex, you have placed `$` inside `[]`, so it matches it literally

Comment: OP should note that escaping `.` or `?` inside `[]` is not required :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`[.?!](?:\s|$)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfulTs/1)

**Explanation:**

- `[.?!]` - matches either a `.` or a `?` or a `!` literally
- `(?:\s|$)` - matches either a white-space or the End-of-line